# How to set up database mirroring and failover?

Tags: devops, failover, database-mirroring

I want to do the database mirroring and failover for my application. I don't know where to find the resource or information about that. so if you used to work on that please recommend me any site or document how to do that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A bit more information? Are you on premise? In the cloud? What type of databases are you talking about?

Comment: What is the your objective, what have you tried so far and result, it could be any relevant source or your work? please kindly describe your problem and what you are trying to achieve in more detail. Thanks

Comment: @DannyThunder I am working on cloud with postgres database.

Comment: @HouyNarun Thank you for your recommendation, I will update more detail than this.